# Rails shows the image URL rather then the image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a [gridview](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid/) of which the grid class (app/grids/users_grid.rb) includes the column below. However, the page does not show the image but instead shows the URL of the image.

```
  column(:name, :html => true, :mandatory => true) do |user|
      user.name + image_path("image.gif", title: "image", style: "max-height: 30px; max-width: 20px")
  end
```

Instead of a name with the image, when loading the page it shows the name with: "/assets/image-d723a44cbcf692df07dbeb65d9ae3d1280f34457d939dafba828a41461623d6c.gif". How can I correct this? Could it have something to do with using `+` in a rb file?

Comment: You can use **image_url** [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/image_url)

Comment: Also when I use `image_url` the problem persists.

Comment: ``image_path`` returns path to an image in your assets. You should use ``image_tag`` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should replace `image_path` with `image_tag`

Try:

```
  column(:name, :html => true, :mandatory => true) do |user|
    content_tag :div do
      content_tag(:span, user.name) + 
      image_tag("image.gif", title: "image", style: "max-height: 30px; max-width: 20px")
    end
  end
```

Comment: Sorry, that's indeed what I originally used (had replaced it with `image_path` to see if that helped). But my post fully applies for `image_tag` the same. So then too same problem.

Comment: weird since thats what the doc states: https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid/wiki/Columns#html-columns-version--091  did you try to remove user name just to check?

Comment: If I remove user.name then the image indeed renders correctly. So then not the url but the actual image. Might be an ussue of the gem...?

Comment: Thanks, tried it, but has the same result: it shows the url of the image rather then the image itself.

Comment: I cant believe I wrote `image_path` and not `image_tag`, re edited

Comment: And I can't believe I noticed that ;-) Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
column(:name, :html => true, :mandatory => true) do |user|
  user.name + image_tag("/assets/image.gif", title: "image", style: "max-height: 30px; max-width: 20px")
end
```

Comment: Same result I'm afraid: it shows the image url rather then the image. Irrespective whether I use image_url or image_tag.

Comment: Using `image_tag("/assets/image.gif"...` produces the name and then `<img title="image" style="max-height: 30px; max-width: 20px" src="/images/assets/image.gif" alt="Image" />` instead of the actual image.